# Trying to find a neat way to process permutation input in python

Tags: python, list, input, integer, permutation

The input is an unknown number of permutations and I want to process it in multiple lists with each permutation. So for example, input is "(1,2,3)(5,3,2)(2,4,1)" and I want it as [[1,2,3],[5,3,2],[2,4,1]]

any ideas?

Comment: Split on `)(`? What have you tried?

Comment: So you receive a list of tuples or a single string? Please share some code to represent your problem, as it is right now, it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one liner you can use.

```
s = "(1,2,3)(5,3,2)(2,4,1)"
s = [list(map(int, x.lstrip('(').rstrip(')').split(','))) for x in s.split(')(')]
print(s)

#Output
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 2], [2, 4, 1]]
```

First we split by `')('`. But we must also remove the starting and closing brackets. We use `lstrip` and `rstrip` for that.

The inner `split(',')` then separates the numbers. We then convert them to `int` using `map` and wrap them in the inner `list`.